# How to properly wait for a partition to get mounted in a systemd service file

Tags: systemd, mount, partition, systemctl

I have a problem during startup of my device running embedded Linux. My systemd service runs before some partitions get mounted which is not acceptable.

I list my mounts with `systemctl list-units --type=mount` and see the .mount files.

In my systemd service file i've now made modifications to wait until these get mounted. My mounts are `opt-abc.mount` and `opt-def.mount` for example and I use both `After` and `Requires` to wait for these to get mounted.

However, there are so many mixed opinions on the best way to do this. `RequiresMountsFor=` , some have recommended not to use this due to nonauto mounts.

Any help / experience with this would be appreciated.

The Unit section of my service file now looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service 

After=opt-abc.mount
After=opt-def.mount
Requires=opt-abc.mount
Requires=opt-def.mount
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both After= and Requires=  can get space separated list of units. So, you don't need multiple assignments (More, I think thats potential for unexpectable result).

The next, After= and Requires= difference. Have a look at this https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html manual. In two words: Requires= is for build dependencies. After= is for execution order.

I believe, that you need only After=. Remember that mount-targets may be generated by fstab or something. It seems, it's bad practice to use generated units in Requires=.